# how to read text file from pc in E: directory in php on live server

Tags: php, file

I have a text file in my pc in E: drive I read this file in php local host it is working properly
but when want to read from live site is not working.
on local host this this my code

```
$myFile = "E:\\textfile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');

if ($fh) {
$array = explode("\n", fread($fh, filesize($myFile)));
}

fclose($fh);

foreach($array as $v){

$data=explode("*",$v);

$msg=$data[0];

$num=$data[1];

}
```

but same code is not work on live site from cpanel

Comment: Off course you can't do such a thing.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple : you can't... server-side code runs on server, so you can't access client. The fact it works on your local environment is only because your server is then the same machine as you client.
You should either ask the user to upload the file to the server, then process it, or store the file on your server if it isn't supposed to be provided by the user...